# ERRO " Call to a member function setCodigo() on a non-object in"

Tags: php, mysql

A programação é em php orientada a objetos e MVC.

Estou fazendo um cadastro de usuários e salvando-o no banco de dados, porém aparece o seguinte erro:

> Call to a member function setCodigo() on a non-object in

o que está causando esse erro?

```
if ($_POST) {
    $codigo = isset($_POST["codigo"]) ? $_POST["codigo"] : false;
    $nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? $_POST["nome"] : false;
    $usuario = isset($_POST["usuario"]) ? $_POST["usuario"] : false;
    $senha = isset($_POST["senha"]) ? $_POST["senha"] : false;

    $usuario->setCodigo($codigo);
    $usuario->setNome($nome);
    $usuario->setUsuario($usuario);
    $usuario->setSenha($senha);

    $usuarioDao->salvar($usuario);
    header("location: ListaUsuario.php");
    exit();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vinda ao SOpt, seria legal você editar sua pergunta adicionando seus códigos para que o pessoal possa te ajudar :D

Comment: Seja bem-vinda ao SOpt, por favor, poste a classe que contém a função setCodigo, para podermos lhe ajudar, você está dando um require corretamente, ele está com encapsulamento público, privado... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei como está seu código inteiro, se usas o require corretamente, mas pelo que vi, você não iniciou a classe usando o `new`, e já está usando a variável `$usuario` .
Você tem que instanciar a classe e atribuir uma variável única pra ela!

Exemplo:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $codigo = isset($_POST["codigo"]) ? $_POST["codigo"] : false;
    $nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? $_POST["nome"] : false;
    $usuarios = isset($_POST["usuario"]) ? $_POST["usuario"] : false;
    $senha = isset($_POST["senha"]) ? $_POST["senha"] : false;

    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $usuario->setCodigo($codigo);
    $usuario->setNome($nome);
    $usuario->setUsuario($usuarios);
    $usuario->setSenha($senha);

    $usuarioDao->salvar($usuario);
    header("location: ListaUsuario.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Olá, a instância do usuário, está na linha acima do meu código, porém fica difícil postar todo o código para descobrir o erro.

Comment: A programação é composta por três classes: FormUsuário.php(Contém os campos do formulário e as variáveis que recebem do $_POST), UsuarioDao.php(Contém métodos que tem a função de salvar, recuperar, listar e excluir um usuário) e Usuario.php(a classe da foto acima, contendo os getters e setters dos atributos).

Comment: Olá, mas vi que você fez: `$usuario = isset($_POST["usuario"]) ? $_POST["usuario"] : false;` e depois orientou usando esta variável `$usuario`, mesmo se ela tiver sido iniciada, quando chegou nessa parte do código, ela passou a valer outra coisa.

Comment: Muito Obrigada Cassiano José! era esse mesmo o erro! eu estava utilizando a variável $usuario para o receber do $_POST e para a classe.

Comment: Por nada! isso sempre acontecia comigo.